# Quartz.net: avoid huge database, stop future triggers, dump scheduled tasks

Tags: scheduling, quartz.net

A couple of questions for the real Quartz gurus out there!

I am a Quartz.net beginner and hoping for some advice before I get burnt:

1) I schedule a bunch of jobs/triggers to go off at specific times in the future. After those tasks are finished I have no more use for the job/trigger information in the database. Is there anything I need to do to avoid a huge database buildup of Quartz events, or do they take care of themselves and automatically get deleted?

2) Various tasks of mine repeat periodically. But sometimes, as I am running the actual job, I realize that I no longer want to continue running periodic events until the job expiry time. How do I stop all future triggers from within an executing job?

3) Is there any way to dump all scheduled tasks. Sometime like "scheduler.DumpAll() ;-)"?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

1. See answer from LeftyX (and my follow-up comment): under normal circumstances, when a trigger has no more fire times it is deleted, and when a job has no more triggers, it is deleted
2. You can use scheduler.unschduleJob(), scheduler.deleteJob(), scheduler.pauseJob(), scheduler.pauseTrigger() - depending upon the specific behavior you actually want.
3. Nope.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am late ;-) but I've just started using Quartz.net recently.
The documentations says:

```
Durable - if a job is non-durable, it is automatically deleted from the 
scheduler once there are no longer any active triggers associated with it.
```

so you can define Durable = false for your job detail and it should be deleted when it expires.

Comment: This is correct, under normal circumstances, when a trigger has no more fire times it is deleted, and when a job has no more triggers, it is deleted.